# Local server and GitHub URL (Jekyll)

Tags: html, jekyll

I'm using Jekyll to build my personal blog.
With my local server served by `jekyll serve --baseurl`, all of my HTML pages work totally fine, but when I push them to GitHub and try to enter the pages, browser returns a 404 error.
One example: My baseurl for the blog is `https://(github-username).github.io/(repo-name)/` and the permalink for one of my pages is `/daily-thoughts/post-1`. On a local server `http://127.0.0.1:4000/daily-thoughts/post-1` this works totally fine but after pushing it to GitHub, the url `https://dragontony1.github.io/dtB/daily-thoughts/post-1` doesn't work, and the same thing happens with all of the other pages too.
Any ways to solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: **`https://dragontony1.github.io/dtB/daily-thoughts/dt-test-post-1`** URL works fine for me.

Comment: _https://dragontony1.github.io/dtB/daily-thoughts/dt-test-post-1_ URL also works for me. I see "Daily thoughts", some Korean words and `placeholder`. Maybe you went too fast and the GitHub pages did not refresh on time. To avoid that, either try to test on private windows or through another browser to have a cleared cache.

Comment: Thx guys I fixed the problem :D